# Parsing binary file with mixed structure

Tags: php, binary

I need to parse a binary ABIF file in PHP. There is the structure: https://projects.nfstc.org/workshops/resources/articles/ABIF_File_Format.pdf

The file consists three logical parts. Header is fixed at the first 128 bytes, other two parts can be anywhere, it means even between some text or XML data. How to parse this two parts? Any ideas?

I found many solutions how to parse ABIF on other languages: Python, C, C++, VB, Perl, JavaScript but nothing at all about PHP. There is the example in JS: https://github.com/eamitchell/ab1ToJSON

There is the file example: https://sourceforge.net/p/seqmanager/code-0/1/tree//cgi-bin/ABIveiw/test.ab1

```
$filename = 'files/2p_Pro_1.ab1';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
$size = filesize ($filename);
$data = fread($handle, 6);
$data = unpack('a4header/nver', $data);
$result['head'] = $data;

$data = fread($handle, 28);
$data = unpack('a4name/Nnumber/nelementtype/nelementsize/Nnumelements/Ndatasize/Ndataoffset/Ndatahandle', $data);
$result['dir'] = $data;

var_dump($result);
```

It returns:

```
Array ( 
    [head] => Array ( 
        [header] => ABIF 
        [ver] => 101 
    ) 
    [dir] => Array ( 
        [name] => tdir 
        [number] => 1
        [elementtype] => 1023 
        [elementsize] => 28 
        [numelements] => 165 
        [datasize] => 4928 
        [dataoffset] => 245963
        [datahandle] => 0
    )
)
```

Comment: The PDF document seems to be a very clear explanation of the file format. What problem are you having in writing the code to parse it?

Comment: It's clear for me how to parse header, 'cause it have fixed position and fixed size. How to parse other elements, if their position is different from file to file? What do i need to use?

Comment: The `dataoffset` tells you where the directory starts. Each directory entry has another `dataoffset` field that tells where its data starts.

Comment: @deji You should post an answer to your question, if you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dataoffset` tells where the directory starts. Each directory entry has another `dataoffset` field that tells where its data starts.